# Перехват трафика TCP

Tags: java, android, tcp

От моего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932110/tcp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-tetra) вытекает следующий вопрос:
можно ли на андроиде перехватить TCP трафик? *На устройстве нету TCP*.
Я не могу создать VPN и пересылать трафик на другой сервер т.к. нету TCP

Android 6 (спец. устройство)
На устройстве, связь с миром возможна только по протоколу TETRA (нету ни 3G, ни GPRS, WIFI)

Comment: А WiFi есть? Установите раздачу WiFi с компьютера, подключитесь к ней и используем wireshark.

Comment: нету, к сожалению